# Understanding symbol/notation in Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, notation, irreducible-polynomials

I know that:

$F(\alpha) = F[X]/f(x)$
where $F[x] = \{a_{n}x^{n} + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ... +a_{1}x+a_{0} \mid a_{i} \in F\}$ is ring of polynomials over F and $f(x)$ is irreducible polynomial in $F[X]$  and $\alpha$ is its root.

and $F(\alpha) = a_{d-1}\alpha^{d-1} + a_{n-1}\alpha^{d-2} + ... +a_{1}\alpha+a_{0} $

but I'm not getting the meaning of

$ Z[\alpha] = Z[X]/fZ[X]$ $ |$ $ f$ is irreducible in  $\in$ $Z[X] $ of degree $d$ and  $\alpha$ is root $\alpha = (X$ mod $fZ[X])$

$Z[\alpha] = Z.1 \oplus Z.\alpha \oplus Z.\alpha^{2} \oplus .... Z.\alpha^{d-1} $

why can't we write it as:

$Z(\alpha) = Z[X]/f(x)$ and

$Z(\alpha) = a_{d-1}\alpha^{d-1} + a_{n-1}\alpha^{d-2} + ... +a_{1}\alpha+a_{0} $

**Secondly**

$K$ and $Q$ are field and $K$ is an extension field of $Q$ of degree n. We write it as:
$[K:Q]=n$.

but I'm not getting the meaning of:

$[\mathcal{O} : Z] =n$ are they same or different?

What is the difference between these ($[K:Q]=n$ , $[\mathcal{O} : Z] =n$) notations and when to use the specific one?.

Please try to explain it at your lowest possible level. Thank you.